# Writing code for generating Cayley's graphs?

Tags: abstract-algebra, graph-theory, algorithms

I am trying to write a program that computes and draws Cayley graphs in Mathematica, I am using the quaternionic group as an example:

$$\mathrm{Q}_8 = \langle a,b \mid a^4 = e, a^2 = b^2, aba = b\rangle$$

Which according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_group#Compared_to_dihedral_group) has the following Cayley graph:

> [image]

Now this is what I got:

> [image]

Which doesn't make sense (there should be two arrows leaving any vertex in the graph). I think the problem is in the following, I thought about defining the following set of strings:

$$G=\{\text{e},\text{a},\text{aa},\text{aaa},\text{ab},\text{aab},\text{aaab},\text{b}\}$$

At another step in my code, I construct a set $S$ of strings such as `aaaabbaabbabbabba` by concatenating elements of $G$ with $a$ and $b$ and then I apply the following substitution rules (based on the relations of the group):

- $r1:$ Switch $aaaa$ for $e$.
- $r2:$ Switch $aba$ for $b$.
- $r3:$ Switch $aa$ for $bb$.
- $r4:$ Switch $b$ for $aba$.
- $r5:$ Switch $bb$ for $aa$.
- $r6:$ Switch $ex$ for $x$ and $xe$ for $x$, for any $x$.

Repeatedly in $S$, in the following order: $r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6$.

Believing it would "converge", ie: Eventually every string in $S$ would be a string in $G$. But that happens only when the rules are more "well behaved" such as $\langle a,b \mid a^2 = e, b^2 = e, ba = ab^2\rangle$. I noticed that some strings "converge" for certain orders of rule applications but not for others. For example: If you take the string `aaba`

- Applying $r2$ to it: `aaba` $\to$ `ab`.
- Applying $r3$ and then $r2$ to it:  `aaba` $\to$ `bbab` $\to$`bbab`.

And it seems this changes depending on the string and hence, it seems we would need to use different orders for each element in $G$. My problem is:

- Is there a way to determine a "best order" of substitution for each element?

I'm not really sure how to tag this question.

Comment: I don't understand how you can have a node for aba when your substitution rules should reduce that to b.

Comment: All your representations of the elements are of the form $a^mb^n$. One rule order that should always work is to first use a rule to shift all the $b$'s to the right ($ba\rightarrow aaab$), and once that no longer works, reduce the number of b's ($bb\rightarrow aa$), and finally reduce the number of $a$'s ($aaaa\rightarrow e$).

Comment: @JaapScherphuis That happens because of the order. For example: `aba`$\stackrel{r_1}{\to}$ `aba`, `aba`$\stackrel{r_2}{\to}$ `b`, `b`$\stackrel{r_3}{\to}$ `b`, `b`$\stackrel{r_4}{\to}$ `aba`, `aba`$\stackrel{r_5}{\to}$ `aba`, `aba`$\stackrel{r_6}{\to}$ `aba`. Ie: I thought applying the substitutions mindlessly would work but it won't. So we must make some kind of strategy to pick the correct sequence of substitutions for each string.

Comment: Got it. My other comment still stands though. Whenever possible you should only use rules that bring it closer to your preferred form, so in particular you should never have any rules that are inverses of each other because one would improve it while the other makes it worse. That works in this case because it is relatively straightforward to judge such improvement. In general however this is related to the [word problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_problem_(mathematics)) which is notoriously hard.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis But the trouble is that for some elements, the inverse is going to be needed. I think I know a way to do it: I split the rules in two sets: "Rules" and "inverse rules" and then I apply the rules in the set "rules" repeatedly in a word. If after $n$ iterations, a word is not in $G$, then it starts applying the "inverse rules" repeatedly, if after $n$ iterations, the word is not in $G$, it applies the "rules" again and so on.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Yeah, the **word** problem is - In the **words** of Extreme - [more than **words**](https://youtu.be/UrIiLvg58SY). $\tiny\text{Sorry.}$

Comment: No, in this case you never need inverses. As I said in my second comment, just shift the b's to the right of any a's using ba->aaab, and once all the b's are at the end you can start reducing their number by replacing bb->aa (from left to right so that the a's stay on the left). Lastly reduce the a's with aaaa->. There is never any need to reverse any step here.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis But this is more or less adapted to this case, right? Or is it a general idea, that in any group we can somehow find a shift and work through it?